# What is the Vegan home planet in 'Cities in Flight'?

Tags: cities-in-flight

In James Blish's *Cities in Flight* tetraology there are mentions of the war between Earth colonists and the Vegan Confederation that ruled half the galaxy.  Naturally the Vegans come from Vega, or Alpha Lyrae.

But I forget if the Vegan home world is described as Vega II (Vega Two), or as Vega 11 (Vega Eleven).

Does anyone know which Vegan planet was the home world of the Vegans?

Comment: Tee hee. War between Terrans and [Vegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism).

Comment: @Lexible - The natives of planets orbiting the star Vega (Alpha Lyrae) are naturally described as Vegans, and in this case they looked similar enough to humans for non humans to count them as humans.  I remember one old story which mentioned a species of intelligent Vegans who looked like 400 foot long dragons.  A war with them would be no joke.  I suppose that if I mentioned Tamar, the Queen of Kings of Georgia, you would say there has never been a monarchy in Georgia.  And it is not so odd for Vegans to have the same name as vegans.

Comment: I am not sure what point you are making, the lighthearted humor of my comment seems to have eluded you, and I assure you lighthearted humor was the entirety of the intent. Your supposition seems baseless,  and is certainly fallacious. (By the bye... was the 400 foot long dragons in Doc Smith's Lensmen series? That's ringing vague bells from several decades back...)

Comment: @M.A.Golding - As long as they don't eat meat, I don't think it would be too bad.

Comment: @Lexible - If you make your kind of joke, l'll make my kind of joke. No, the Velantians in the Lensman series were "only" 30 feet long and didn't come from anywhere near Vega.  I was referring to an old humorous short story where someone had a job dealing with aliens and he mentioned those 400 foot long Vegans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vega II (e.g. the second world of the Vega system).

> *The capital world of the Tyranny, **Vega II**, was invested in 2413 by a
> number of armed cities, including IMT, whose task it was to destroy
> the many orbital forts surrounding the planet, and by the Third
> Colonial Navy under Admiral Alois Hrunta, who was charged with
> occupying Vega II in the event of its surrender.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Cities in Flight: Omnibus Edition](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/141805.Cities_in_Flight)</sup></sub>

Comment: This looks like an except from the history taught to Crispin De Ford in A Life For the Stars.  Did you type it in, or cut an paste from an online version, thus preserving the typeface?  The latter case would make it certain it was Vega Two instead of Vega Eleven. making it certain

Comment: @M.A.Golding - I copied and pasted it from the e-Book edition. You may note that this copy tallies with the copy lodged with Google Books; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DyrUwsEzsREC&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25&dq=%22The+capital+world+of+the+Tyranny,+Vega+II%22&source=bl&ots=fAj5dAAdjW&sig=2Sm8CDunFALYRkwLFEbYHSLwI7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-s43d8NPZAhWLJsAKHbkuCJMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20capital%20world%20of%20the%20Tyranny%2C%20Vega%20II%22&f=false

Comment: Thank you.  That was fast!  So the typeface shows it was Vega 2.

Comment: @M.A.Golding If you think this is the correct answer, please click on the checkmark to indicate that.